# PHP how to get file read the next lLine

Tags: php, file

I have a file that has 4 values per line separated by : and am now trying to read from that file. the file has multiple lines all with the same format but for some reason when I read from it only the first line is getting read. I've tried

```
$baseFileHandle = fopen($baseFileLocation, 'r') or die("Error In Opening Inventory File Please Contact a System Developer");
           $inline = fgets($baseFileHandle, 4096);
           if ($baseFileHandle) 
           {
               while (($line = fgets($baseFileHandle)) !== false) {
           list($lItem_id,$lItem_name,$lQuantity,$lThreshold) = explode(':',$inline);
               //var_dump($_POST);
               $temp_item = $this->model('Temp_Inventory');
               $temp_item->item_name = $lItem_name;
               $temp_item->quantity = $lQuantity;
               $temp_item->threshold = $lThreshold;
               $temp_item->inventory_id = $lItem_id;               
               $temp_item->insert(); 
           }

           fclose($baseFileHandle);
```

as well as

```
$inline = fgets($baseFileHandle, 4096);
            
            while (!feof($baseFileHandle) && !($found)) 
            {
                list($lItem_id,$lItem_name,$lQuantity,$lThreshold) = explode(':',$inline);
                //var_dump($_POST);
                $temp_item = $this->model('Temp_Inventory');
                $temp_item->item_name = $lItem_name;
                $temp_item->quantity = $lQuantity;
                $temp_item->threshold = $lThreshold;
                $temp_item->inventory_id = $lItem_id;               
                $temp_item->insert(); 
                fgets($baseFileHandle, 4096);
                //redirecttoaction
            }
            fclose($baseFileHandle);
```

but I cant seem to get it to work any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm fairly new to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do this:

```
$file = fopen($baseFileLocation, 'r') or die("Error In Opening Inventory File Please Contact a System Developer");

while (!feof($file)) {
    $inline = fgets($file, 4096);
    list($lItem_id,$lItem_name,$lQuantity,$lThreshold) = explode(':',$inline);
    $temp_item = $this->model('Temp_Inventory');
    $temp_item->item_name = $lItem_name;
    $temp_item->quantity = $lQuantity;
    $temp_item->threshold = $lThreshold;
    $temp_item->inventory_id = $lItem_id;               
    $temp_item->insert(); 
}

fclose($file);
```

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fgets.asp